# Implementing Mathematica Machine Learning Algorithm in an HTML-Web Page

Tags: machine-learning, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I have a Mathematica Neural Network developed in Mathematica 11.2 that I'd like to upload and use on my website. The algorithm takes in images as an input. My website is built with HTML-CSS and Flask.

How can I implement this Mathematica on my website? Is there a way I can implement it on my website using Wolfram Cloud?

Else, can I implement Mathematica into Python code?

Comment: You can export your network as an MXNet network with `Export["myNetwork.json", myNetwork, "MXNet"]`. This should allow you to use the ["amalgamation" feature of MXNet](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/amalgamation) to deploy into a web page. If that doesn't work, you should be able to use the network from Python relatively easily via MXNet's libraries.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention is that `NetEncoder` and `NetDecoder` don't come with when you export as that format - you will probably have to write code to send input and receive output from your network in a format matching what WL does.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as you, I'm looking at using EmbedCode and CloudDeploy to embed in an HTML web page.